# Week Number in python for regression

Tags: python, date, format, regression

My current data set is by Fiscal Week. It is in this format "FY2013 WK 2". How can I format it, so that I can use a regression model on it and predict a value for let's say "FY2017 WK 2".

Should I treat Fiscal Week as a categorical value and use dmatrices?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using regression to predict on the domain not spanned by your training data, are you?

Comment: Not sure I understand. My training data is 2013-2015 and my testing data is 2016. I will be predicting 2017.

Comment: You likely shouldn't be using regression. What you are trying to do is called [extrapolating](https://xkcd.com/605/).

Comment: thank you - but wouldn't I need to change the fiscal week format for extrapolating as well?

Comment: also, when googling extrapolation http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219579/what-is-wrong-with-extrapolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the string describing the week into an integer you can use as the abscissa (x-coordinate, or independent variable).  Pick a "zero point", such as **FY2012 WK 52**, so that **FY2013 WK 01** translates to the integer 1.

I don't that DateTime handles this conversion; you might have to code the translation yourself: parse the string into year and week integers, and compute the abscissa from that:

> 52*(year-2013) + week

You might also want to keep a dictionary of those translations, as well as a reverse list (week => FY_week) for output labelling.

Does that move you toward a solution you can implement?